# Python,nested list access

Tags: python-3.x, nested

I have this nested list:

```
food = ['apple', ['apple2', ['apple3', ['apple4', ['last apple', None]]]]]
```

Is there a way to have access this list without using multiple brackets(etc. `food[i][j]`...)

Comment: Why not use multiple brackets? That would be the cleanest way.

Comment: because  i want to use a while loop in order to access it

Comment: How does using a while loop prevent you from using multiple brackets?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: @Carcigenicate could you suggest me a way with while loop and multiple brackets?

Comment: @vasilyi You'd need to show more context about what you're trying to do. I can't see how you'd be prevented from using brackets, so it would be hard for me to write a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want to print everything(apple,apple1(below)...etc) in the list except None.

Comment: The first element in each list is the message. The second element of every list is the next list. Think about grabbing the first element of the list and printing it, then grabbing the second element of the list and doing the same to it that you did to the outer list, over and over. I'm hesitant to create an answer now though, because this looks like homework, and it would be difficult for me to answer this without giving the outright solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `operator.itemgetter` in a nested call, though I don't know why you would want to do this. For example to get `'apple4'` at `food[1][1][1][0]`,

```
from operator import itemgetter

get_0 = itemgetter(0)
get_1 = itemgetter(1)

print(get_0(get_1(get_1(get_1(food)))))  # -> apple4
```